# Is there a way to find all Primal spells with a Will save?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-2e

When I tried to search AoN (Archives of Nethys) for "Will primal", I got [some spells](https://2e.aonprd.com/Search.aspx?Query=Will%20primal&Filter=000000000000001&AllTerms=True&OneLine=False&ExcludeAPModule=False&PFSLegalOnly=False), but it seems the search only looks for the keywords in the *body*, but not in the header, basically the opposite of what I need.

Is there a way other than going through the primal spell list manually?

Comment: As written, I am having a hard time not seeing this as a tool recommendation, which is off topic. But, you can simply reword the question as the real problem you are trying to solve: "what are all the Primal spells with a Will save?"

Comment: Alternatively, this could be a question on how to best use Archive of Nethys search, in which case this seems like less of a tool recommendation and more of how to use a (very common) PF2e tool. I'd think that either this question (or the one @ThomasMarkov recommends) would be stackable.

Comment: @ESCE That is a good suggestion as well, we have precedent for that kind of question.

Comment: Are you sure you're getting nothing? I followed your link and got a list of spells.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov those spells aren't Primal spells with Will saves, though, which I assume (from the title) is what we are looking for. So "nothing" is technically incorrect; it's just wrong results. As a test case, our search should definitely return [Fear](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=110)

Comment: @ESCE Yeah, I see that now. It looks like searching just "Will" returns no results despite there being plenty of spell descriptions with that string.

Comment: I think that AoN only searches the spell text (and maybe name?), not the keywords, which is why the above search doesn't work.

Comment: I'm guessing it searches the results you get in the [Table View](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?Tradition=4) (Name, Source, Tradition(s), Rarity, Traits, and Summary) but not the actual text of the spell. I'll be interested if anyone can solve this if/when this is reopened.

Comment: @ESCE, it seems I misunderstood the `tool` tag. I really do not need a tool recommendation, but help to get these spells

Comment: Actually, a tool recommendation seems like exactly what might be called for. Since AoN can't do it, and, as we see below, another website can...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Currently, the Primal spells that require a Will save are the following:**

Tame, Charm, Fear, Lose the Path, Positive Attunement, Compel True Name, Banishment, Glimmer of Charm, Mariner's Curse, Ravening Maw, Blanket of Stars, Blinding Fury, Catch Your Name, and Burning Blossoms.

As of this answer, Archives of Nethys is not well suited for searching on the basis of spell saving throw type or tradition. Its search function looks at the name and text of a spell, but not its other characteristics. Furthermore, AoN's spell index is not otherwise filterable by saving throw type.

Instead, this list was gathered using [PF2 Easy Tools](https://pf2easy.com/spellbook/), which provides slightly better spell filtering functionality than Archives of Nethys. I retrieved the list by:

- Filtering the total spell list by the Primal tradition (using the top menu options)

[image: Primal Tradition Filter]

- Entering "Will" in the save type filter in the table generated below.

[image: Saving Throw Type Filter]

Comment: @ESCE Technically Nethys has a list of all primal spells and you can cross reference this with the search redults for "will save" and "will saving" to get almost the same results (Ravening Maw would be missing). So you'd still need to use excel or coding or something to cross reference quickly, but it can be done non-manually. Or just use any of a number of potentially less-than-legal other sites that do all the sorting for you

Comment: @Cellion I would actually suggest expanding your answer to include that PF2 Easy Tools link, and maybe a brief description of how you got the result; seeing as the question is asking for *how* to find this information, rather than a list. (It'll also make the question/answer a bit more generally useful, which is always good.)

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz I initially wanted to avoid plugging a particular tool to not turn this into a tool recommendation. I'll certainly update if that makes for a more useful answer.

Comment: @Cellion Answers can recommend anything they want—we have policy against questions seeking such recommendations, but if a good answer to a valid question is to recommend a tool (or anything else, though I have a hard time imagining a valid question where recommending a whole game system would be a good answer), then it is entirely valid to recommend a tool. This is, in fact, the explicit recommendation for editing tool recommendation questions: change it from asking for a tool to asking simply “how do I?” and then if there is a useful tool for that purpose, that will be a good answer.

Answer (score 4):

### It is possible now in Archives of Nethys

The [search options improved a lot](https://2e.aonprd.com/Search.aspx?q=saving_throw%3Awill%20tradition%3Aprimal&type=eqs&include-types=spell&display=list), now you can filter it with "tradition:primal" and "saving_throw:will".

Comment: why is ## better than ==?

Comment: See this [meta post](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12472/72765), mainly due to accessibility issues with having more than one H1 header on a page.